# Which columns should be key in dimension (SSAS)?

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence

Which column from the attribute can I use as a key when I create a dimension in SSAS?

I can't use "id" because it is a surrogacy key that should not be used in the dimension.

The table is part of a DW databasemodel.

Table Dim_Demographics:

- id
- Sex
- marital status
- yearly
- salary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a dimension, the key column needs to be the one that is linked to the fact table in the DSV.